# Changes made for comment

Tags: feature-request, comments, edits

There is an option to see the edit done for the post for both the answer and question. Why not the same feature for a comment?

If a user made any change on a comment as the same way showing `edited before few minute` and what changes are done. Also the comment order updating is based on the final edit.

Comment: Wait. There's a pencil already after the comment date if it has been edited, see it? -->>

Comment: @nicael : really... I didn't even noticed that ... thanks man :)

Comment: As a note, edits to comments have a five minute window only... after that, only mods can edit comments. Edits to questions and answers within a similar five minute window are not shown, either. So, really, they're treated more "severely" since you can see that there was an edit made **and** you only have five minutes to make that edit.

Comment: OK... how is this "can no longer be reproduced"? The question is asking for an edit history for comments... which doesn't exist. Yes, we have the pencil showing **that** it's been edited... but we can't see what the past edits were.

Comment: I thought "no repro" CV is for bugs? *Shrug*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no way to see updates to comments for normal users. Moderators can only see final edits (so after the 5 minute edit window, all intermediate changes are not registered). Moderators can edit comments of anyone after the 5 minutes window we as normal users have.

You can see there was an edit on a comment: a small pencil will tell you when it has changed.

I am not sure if a revision history for comments is really useful to regular users, so that would be a *no* for me. The pencil suffices.